# how to add graphql to heroku in a strapi app?

Tags: url, heroku, deployment, graphql, strapi

I made a Strapi app using MongoDb, Cloudinary (for the images) and Heroku (for deployment). I installed Graphql before deploying it. It works fine in develop mode in localhost, the graphql playground shows normally. But in production I get an error when trying to show graphql playground. It just shows a blank page with this message:

GET query missing

How can I query my data using graphql/Apollo if the url "some_name.heroku.com/graphql" doesn't work?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I found out in a github forum that I had to add some code in the plugins.js file to make graphql work in production.
This is the code:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  //
  graphql: {
     config: {
        endpoint: "/graphql",
        shadowCRUD: true,
        playgroundAlways: true,
        depthLimit: 100,
        apolloServer: {
          tracing: false,
          },
        },
     }, 
   });
```

after that I had to commit the changes in my repo and wait to heroku to deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for Strapi v3 (3.6.10)

Path — `./plugins/graphql/config/settings.json`

```
{
  "endpoint": "/graphql",
  "tracing": false,
  "shadowCRUD": true,
  "playgroundAlways": true,
  "depthLimit": 7,
  "amountLimit": 100
}
```